# Отправка файла на сервер без формы yii2?

Tags: yii2, upload

Мне надо отправить на хостинг с компа картинку.
Что я уже сделал:
Отправляю через консоль:

```
$file = Yii::getAlias('@upload') . "/pic.jpg";
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $client = new Client(['baseUrl' => Yii::$app->params['site_api']]);
        $response = $client->createRequest()
            ->setMethod('post')
            ->setUrl('api')
            ->addFile('file', $file)
            ->send();
    }
```

Дальше принимающий контроллер

```
 $UploadedFile = UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('file');
```

тут все нормально, файл приходит

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => yii\web\UploadedFile Object
        (
            [name] => pic.jpg
            [tempName] => /tmp/phpZC03Gz
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [size] => 18620
            [error] => 0
        )

    )
```

а вот как дальше сохранить картинку в нужную мне директорию?

Answer (score 1):

У модели `UploadedFile` [есть метод `saveAs()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#saveAs()-detail).

Соответственно вам необходимо его вызвать и передать путь, куда вы хотите сохранить этот файл:

```
$UploadedFile[0]->saveAs('path_to_file')
```

Comment: Блин, спасибо, вот я ошибся, я все пытался `$UploadedFile->saveAs`.

Comment: а может знаете как из первого контроллера еще отправить и пост данные, если я добавляю ->setData();  у меня картинка не приходит

Comment: А какой Client вы используете?

Comment: Судя по документации - должно работать https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/blob/master/docs/guide/usage-multi-part-content.md

Comment: ну вот я по этой документации и делаю, но почему-то не работает, или файл, или данные, вместе не идут